# Simplifying calculation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question

My education system won't allow me to use calculator even though within complex number. Luckily, we use multiple choice (which I can do approximation)

I am no human calculator, and if I count, it will take too long. If I do approximation, sometimes I do not know the rule (which impact to false answer)

Is there any mathematic rule to count with approximation?

Ps: this problem most likely found in modern physics (which they have ugly number such as planck's constant, electron weight, etc)

Comment: I have one suggestion which worked quite well for me. (Ive been in your shoes). Try to slightly tweak your values so that some cancellation (between the numerator and denominator) is possible. So, you might have to take planck's constant as $7\times10^{-34}$ or $6\times10^{-34}$ depending on which would cancel better. Also, try to make similar changes in numerator and denominator and/or opposite changes in only numerator or only denominator. Also keep in mind whether the change you made is decreasing or increasing your value below or above the exact answer.

Comment: Another thing you can do is to make every possible value less than 10, that is, for example, $1355 = 1.355 \times 10^{3}$. Doing this, you can calculate the powers of $10$ first, and then check whether the remaining part is more or less than $1$